# How can I change bootstrap tooltip styling for a particular element only?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with id `pls_btn`. I have set tooltip position position to top. But I also want the tooltip to have 100px margin from left. After some digging I found out that `.tooltip-inner` can serve my purpose.
So when I set

```
.tooltip-inner{
     margin-left:100px;
}
```

the changes are reflected on all the tooltips. But when I do

```
#pls_btn .tooltip-inner{
   ..
}
or
#pls_btn>.tooltip-inner{
   ..
}
```

everything works as in default. I want this tooltip styling for one element only. How can I do this ?

Comment: can you share your html part..?

Comment: @Ranjana
`<a id='pls_btn' tooltip-placement='top' tooltip="Add Section or Assessment" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn-lg btn btn-dark-blue dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="width:43px;padding:15px; cursor: pointer;"></i>&nbsp;</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [siblings selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/), see the example below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .blue-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: blue;}
  .blue-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: blue; }
</style>

<div class="well">
  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default blue-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bototm">Blue Tooltip on bottom</button>
  
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```